# Shader in sfml covering entire screen

Tags: c++, glsl, screen, sfml

I am making a game in C++ and sfml, I am using a shader and it's covering the entire screen window.
But I want it to only cover a portion of the screen like the game object or sprite.

Note: Not all the code in the main file is mine but it's pretty generic code for sfml so...

Main file:

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() 
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), "Shaders!!!", sf::Style::Close);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("EnemyShip.png");

    sf::Sprite sprite(texture); //create a sprite from the created texture

    sf::Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromFile("shader.vert", "shader.frag");

    while (window.isOpen()) 
    {
        sf::Event evnt;

        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)) 
        {
            if (evnt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
        window.draw(sprite, &shader); //draw the sprite with blur shader
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

shader.frag:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec4 vertexColor; // the input variable from the vertex shader (same name and same type)  

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}
```

shader.vert

```c
#version 330 core

in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 vertexColor;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(texCoord, 0.0, 1.0);
    vertexColor = vec4(0.5, 0.2, 0.7, 1.0);
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing or can I just reconfigure `gl_Position` to just cover a portion of the screen? (but how would I make the color clear on the other "right" parts of the screen?)

Comment: *" I am using a shader and it's covering the entire screen"* - the shader does not cover anything. The vertex coordinates (and the transformations) define the region which is covered by the primitives. Most likely you have to define a transformation matrix. I recommend to tread a tutorial, for instance [LearnOpenGL - Transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations)

Answer (score 2):

The vertex coordinates (and the transformations) define the region which is covered by the primitives.
You have to define a transformation matrix. (See [LearnOpenGL - Transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations))

Add a [uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variable of they `mat4` to the vertex shader and transform the vertex coordinate by the transformation matrix.

```c
#version 330 core

in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 vertexColor;
uniform mat4 transformMat;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transformMat * vec4(texCoord, 0.0, 1.0);
    vertexColor = vec4(0.5, 0.2, 0.7, 1.0);
}
```

In tha application program, a transformation has to be defined and the uniform hs to be set.

Define a [`sf::Transform`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transform.php) which scales and translates the vertex coordinates. e.g:

```cpp
sf::Transform transform;
transform.scale(0.25f, 0.25f);
transform.translate(-0.5f, -0.5f);
```

Create a [`sf::Glsl::Mat4`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/namespacesf_1_1Glsl.php#a769de806596348a8e56ed6506c688271) from the transformation:

```cpp
sf::Glsl::Mat4 modelMat(transform.getMatrix());
```

Set the transformation matrix to the matrix uniform ([`sf::Shader::setUniform`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Shader.php#aca5c55c4a3b23d21e33dbdaab7990755)):

```cpp
shader.setUniform("transformMat", modelMat);
```

Comment: `Sf::Transform transform` needs to be a pointer for some reason. Also while this does bring the bottom left corner in the correct place, it still leaves a huge area rendered by the shader. Also what if I have the sprite in different locations?

Comment: @Prolight That is much to broad for a single Stack Overflow question. You have to learn about transformations. See [LearnOpenGL - Transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations)

Comment: Oh okay! Much too* (forgot an o)